# Python PIL convert JPEG into black and white color TIFF with DPI limits

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

```
image = Image.open(jpeg_path)
image = image.convert('1')  # this should save the tiff file as black and white?   
tiff_path = jpeg_path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.tiff'
image.save(tiff_path)
```

The above code can convert a JPEG file into TIFF file, but when open the tiff file property it still shows as color.
How to change the Colors to black and white, and how to limit the DPI, for example, to 96?

Note:
The generated tiff file size is about 472KB, but after selecting and save Colors to be Black and white in image properties, the tiff file size changed to 32KB.

[image]

Comment: If I open a PNG, do `convert(1)` and save it as a TIFF, it is a 1 bit per pixel TIFF.  Why do you save a color TIFF first?  By the way, DPI is meaningless here.  It's just a number in the image header.  It doesn't change the pixels in any way.

Comment: Yes, there's no need to save a color TIFF first, I have updated the code, but it still generates 472KB TIFF file with Color ticked in image properties dialog. The TIFF file needs to be imported into another system where has the DPI limits.